# Unable to build Ionic / Cordova iOS due to an issue with the entitlements file or provisioning profile

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ios-provisioning, code-signing-entitlements

When trying to build the iOS version of my Ionic app, it keeps failing with the following message

```
=== BUILD TARGET tlpApp OF PROJECT tlpApp WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "tlpApp" target's 
entitlements file. Remove the entitlements or switch to manual signing and 
resolve the issue by downloading a provisioning profile from the developer 
website.

Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.ionicframework.tlpapp360156" 
doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement.

Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/kenkern/Workspaces/tlp/tlp2/tlp-ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,tlpApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,tlpApp,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,tlpApp.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/kenkern/Workspaces/tlp/tlp2/tlp-ionic/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/kenkern/Workspaces/tlp/tlp2/tlp-ionic/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

This message occurs when running the "ionic build ios" or "cordova build ios" command.  I can emulate the app just fine ("ionic emulate ios").  I also get the same message in XCode when I try to build it to an actual device (like an ipad connected to my mac).

First, I am not sure I understand what it means to either "remove the entitlements" or "switch to manual signing and resolve the issue by downloading a provisioning profile from the developer website".

The bigger question I have is why I am able to build to iOS just fine when I create a simple Ionic app from their template like such?

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics --v2
cd cutePuppyPics
ionic build ios --prod
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am hitting this issue.  It seems that because I am using push, the automatic signing isn't working (though it is working for another project because somewhere along the way a app id specific team provisioning profile was created for it).  It also seems that, even if I specify provisioning profile GUIDs in build.json cordova still creates the project with automatic signing enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As of Cordova v7.0.1, I experience this issue on a regular basis (only when specifying `--release` with the build command, and only with iOS).

My (not ideal) solution has been the following:

1. Open the Xcode project
2. Uncheck `Automatically manage signing`
3. Select an eligible debug provisioning profile from the dropdown
4. Select an eligible release provisioning profile from the dropdown
5. Run `cordova build ios --release`
6. Re-check `Automatically manage signing` (for archiving the project and sending to iTunesConnect)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using push notifications on phonegap or ionic projects, be sure if the push notifications are enable on `capabilites`.